# Get a screenshot from a imageview based on uiview

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on face swapping I am resizing, rotating a `UIView`. I know how to take a regular rectangular screenshots of the iPhone/iPad screen (code below). However, I'm looking for a way to get a screenshot that is rotated by an arbitrary number of degrees

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((userResizeView.bounds.size), false,0)
            var ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

ctx.translateBy(x: -(userResizeView.frame.origin.x), y: -(userResizeView.frame.origin.y))
            imageView.layer.render(in: ctx)[enter image description here][1]
            var viewImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
```

`userResizeView` is my custom third party class(ResizableView).

This is the output which I am getting:

[image]

Comment: This question way to complicated to understand what you want, what you are doing and what is the issue. Is the view snapshot not rotated? Then add it as a subview and make the snapshot of the super view. Anyway what exactly is your result and what is the expected result?

Comment: I want to crop face with particular position and size of image. I am using third party class(ResizableView) for resizing and rotation of uiview. I am able to take screen short normally but when I rotate the uiview it is not working properly. screenshort is taking only in vertical direction.Unable to take screenshort of rotated uiview

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this issue.